# obtaining string as a float variable using regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

have a file with contents:

```
ON abc_4abk_keys44a
keyword : c
START c
hashtags;
START
student_4e;
END
professor_u6;
topper_98j;
A.dim 3.246 burst R1;
B.dim 2.642 burst R6;
K.dimension 3.564 burst L4;
END c
ON amc_4sn_bname1
keyword : k4
START k4
hashtags;
START
student_4e;
END
professor_u6;
topper_98j;
A.dim 3.246 burst R1;
B.dim 2.642 burst R6;
K.dimension 3.564 burst L4;
END k4
```

I want to extract 2.642 from B.dim in all modules where title has keys like abc_4abk_keys44a, for this first I need to search for keys, then in that module from START 'keyword' to END 'keyword', and then extract 2.642 as a float type variable. I cannot figure out the regex to use, can someone help me?

```
import re
import sys

def main()

  path = sys.argv[1]

  with open path as f:
    data = f.read()

  unit = re.findall(r"ON\s+(.*\S)",data)


  if (unit == *keys):
    token = re.findall(r"\.*?B\.dim\s*(.*?)\s*burst",data)

main()
```

Comment: To match up to the last non-whitespace char, you may use `.*\S`, so you might use `ON\s+(.*\S)` pattern (rather than `r"\ON\s+(.*?)\s+\n"`). Could you please add `keys` declaration?

Comment: I cant figure out how to go about the keys part

Comment: Can you not just turn it into a float once you have gotten the string from regex by using `float(string_here)`? Or if it is in a list use `[float(x) for x in list_of_string_floats_here]

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code snippet.

Comment: What is `keys`?

Comment: you be better of by using an stack to track when a record starts and when the record ends.

Comment: so basically keys is something that my module title contains, it is just a string

Comment: Where do you set it? And why are you using `*` before it?

Comment: i want to look for the value between B.dim and burst only in modules with title containing `keys`

Comment: I didnt know how to do that

Comment: `print( re.findall(r'(?m)^ON +abc_4abk_keys44a(?:\n(?!ON +\w+$).*)*?\nB\.dim +(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', data) )`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want to set an `if` condition, the module title can be anything and not specifically the one used above

Comment: could you tell me how I can extract the whole part after `ON` and check for `keys' in it

Comment: Maybe `(?m)^ON +(\w+)(?:\n(?!ON +\w+$).*)*?\nB\.dim +(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`? See https://regex101.com/r/esxTO3/1, check `match.group(1)` and `match.group(2)`.

Comment: yes this is perfect, I need to check if match.group(1) has the word keys in it, how to go about that using an `if` condition

Comment: `if 'keys' in match.group(1):`??? You might also put it in the regex to get the right value, `(?m)^ON +(\w*keys\w*)`...

Comment: `(?m)^ON +(\w*keys\w*)(?:\n(?!ON +\w+$).*)*?\nB\.dim +(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` is this what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using regular expressions, use `split()` to split each line at whitespace.

Loop over all the lines, and set a variable that indicates whether you're in the unit that matches `key`.

```
import sys

def main():
    path = sys.argv[1]
    key = 'abc_4abk_keys44a'
    token = None
    with open(path) as f:
        in_unit = False
        for line in f:
            words = line.split()
            if len(words) == 2 and words[0] == 'ON':
                in_unit = key in words[1]
            if in_unit and len(words) == 4 and words[0] == 'B.dim':
                token = float(words[1])
                break
    print(token)

main()
```

Comment: yes this can work but the key is if the module title contains the word `keys`  and not the whole title, so how should I go about that? could you make the change here

Comment: use `key in words[1]`

Comment: so is there a need for this `key = 'abc_4abk_keys44a'` because this should be a general program, and not specifically for just this module `'abc_4abk_keys44a`

Comment: so what I was thinking was that in your program if we could use regex to obtain `'abc_4abk_keys44a'` and then put it in the form of ` key = 'abc_4abk_keys44a'`

Comment: Regexp is overkill for this.

Comment: so how can I match for the word keys in my module title without regex?

Comment: yes I corrected that but the code doesnt work idk why, it doesnt give an error but no output as well

Comment: What output are you expecting? It never prints anything. I added `print(token)`

Comment: yes i added `print(token)`

Comment: When I added that it printed `2.642`

Comment: it gives an error in mine `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'token' not referenced before assignment

Comment: Did you add `token = None` at the beginning, so it will have a default value if it's not found, like I did?